# Drawing binary tree with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, binary-tree

I have attempted to display binary tree naturally with matplotlib. My tree has form of like this.

```
{'root': [{'left1': [{'left1_2': ['res1', 'res2']}, 'res1']},
      {'right1': [{'left_2': ['res1', 'res2']}, 'res2']}]}
```

As you can see, the tree is something like nested dictionary that has list as a value for each key. And the first element of list has to be locateded at left and the second element of list has to be located at right from parent node. That is, I want the tree to be displayed like this.

[image]


My code as follows.


Define Node class.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,text='',x=None,y=None,isRoot=False,parentNode=None,
                 leftNode=None,rightNode=None,textBox=None,boxWidth=None,
                 ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.text = text
        self.IsRoot = isRoot
        self.parentNode = parentNode
        self.leftNode = leftNode
        self.rightNode = rightNode
        self.textBox = textBox
        self.boxWidth = boxWidth
        self.isTerminal=False

    def getParentNode(self):
        return self.parentNode
    def setParentNode(self,parentNode):
        self.parentNode = parentNode

    def getIsTerminal(self):
        return self.isTerminal
    def setIsTerminal(self, isTerminal):
        self.isTerminal = isTerminal
        return 

    def getLeftNode(self):
        return self.leftNode
    def setLeftNode(self, leftNode):
        self.leftNode = leftNode

    def getRightNode(self):
        return self.rightNode
    def setRightNode(self, rightNode):
        self.rightNode = rightNode

    def getText(self):
        return self.text
    def setText(self,text):
        self.text = text

    def getX(self):
        return self.x
    def setX(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y
    def setY(self,y):
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.x}, {self.y}, {self.text}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'TreeNode({self.x}, {self.y}, {self.text})'
```

Define Tree class.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        import numpy as np
        self.depth = 0
        self.width = 1
        self.height = 1
        self.verticalSpace = 0.5
        self.xMax = -np.infty
        self.xMin = np.infty
        self.yMax = -np.infty
        self.yMin = np.infty

    def createNode(self,text='',x=None,y=None,isRoot=False,
                   parentNode=None,leftNode=None,rightNode=None, isTerminal=False):
        return Node(text,x,y,isRoot,parentNode,leftNode,rightNode,isTerminal)

    def addNode(self,node=None,isLeft=True,text='',x=None,y=None,
                isRoot=False,parentNode=None,isTerminal=False):
        if x+self.width+2 > self.xMax:
            self.setXMax(x+self.width)
        if x-self.width < self.xMin:
            self.setXMin(x-self.width)
        if y > self.yMax:
            self.setYMax(y)
        if y-self.height-self.verticalSpace < self.yMin:
            self.setYMin(y-self.height)

        if node is None:
            return self.createNode(text,x,y,isRoot=True)
        assert isinstance(node,Node)
        if isLeft:
            node.leftNode = self.createNode(text,x,y,parentNode=node,isTerminal=isTerminal)
            return node.leftNode
        else:
            node.rightNode = self.createNode(text,x,y,parentNode=node,isTerminal=isTerminal)
            return node.rightNode

    def getXMax(self):
        return self.xMax
    def setXMax(self,xMax):
        self.xMax = xMax
        return
    def getXMin(self):
        return self.xMin
    def setXMin(self,xMin):
        self.xMin = xMin
        return

    def getYMax(self):
        return self.yMax
    def setYMax(self,yMax):
        self.yMax = yMax
        return
    def getYMin(self):
        return self.yMin
    def setYMin(self,yMin):
        self.yMin = yMin
        return
```

Define "building_tree_node" function which generate decsendant node from the predifined root node.

```
def building_tree_node(tree, node, counter=0):
    box_x = 2
    counter += 1
    for key, value in tree.items():
        node.setText(key)
        if contain_dict(value):
            if isinstance(value[0], dict):
                left_node = TREE.addNode(node=node,x=-box_x*counter,y=-1*counter,
                                         isLeft=True,text=list(value[0].keys())[0])
                building_tree_node(tree=value[0], node=left_node, counter=counter)
                if isinstance(value[1], dict):
                    right_node = TREE.addNode(node=node,x=box_x*counter,y=-1*counter,
                                             isLeft=False,text=list(value[1].keys())[0])
                    building_tree_node(tree=value[1], node=right_node, counter=counter)
                else:
                    temp = TREE.addNode(node=node,x= box_x*counter,y=-1*counter,
                                         isLeft=False,text=value[1])
                    temp.setIsTerminal(True)

            if isinstance(value[1], dict):
                right_node = TREE.addNode(node=node,x=box_x*counter,y=-1*counter,
                                         isLeft=False,text=list(value[1].keys())[0])
                building_tree_node(tree=value[1], node=right_node, counter=counter)
                temp = TREE.addNode(node=node,x=-box_x*counter,y=-1*counter,
                                         isLeft=True,text=value[0])
                temp.setIsTerminal(True)
        else:
            temp = TREE.addNode(node=node,x=-box_x*counter,y=-1*counter,
                                         isLeft=True,text=value[0])
            temp.setIsTerminal(True)
            temp = TREE.addNode(node=node,x= box_x*counter,y=-1*counter,
                                         isLeft=False,text=value[1])
            temp.setIsTerminal(True)

    final_tree = TREE
    final_root = node

    return final_tree, final_root
```

Helper function

```
def contain_dict(l):
    res = False
    for v in l:
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            res = True
    return res
```

Generate tree and TREE class and root Node.

```
tree = dict()
left1 = dict()
right1 = dict()
left1['left1'] = [{'left1_2':['res1','res2']},'res1']
right1['right1'] = [{'left2_2':['res1','res2']},'res2']
tree['root'] = [left1, right1]

TREE = Tree()
root = TREE.addNode(x=0,y=0,text='root')
```

Define function which draws a tree.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ft, fr = building_tree_node(tree,root) ## final_tree, root node has all decsendants

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.set_xlim(ft.getXMin(),ft.getXMax())
ax.set_ylim(ft.getYMin(),ft.getYMax()+1)
width = ft.width
height = ft.height

def drawNode(node):
    if node is not None:
        if node.getIsTerminal():
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='square',fc='green')
        else:
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='square',fc='yellow')
        text_box = ax.text(node.getX(),node.getY(),node.getText(),bbox=bbox,fontsize=15,ha='center',va='center')  
        node.textBox = text_box
        if node.parentNode is not None:
            parentTextBox = node.parentNode.textBox
            pbb = parentTextBox.get_window_extent(renderer=renderer).inverse_transformed(ax.transData)
            currentTextBox = node.textBox
            cbb = currentTextBox.get_window_extent(renderer=renderer).inverse_transformed(ax.transData)
            ax.plot((node.parentNode.x, node.x), (node.parentNode.y-pbb.height*0.7, node.y),color='k')
        drawNode(node.leftNode)
        drawNode(node.rightNode)
```

When I run my code as follows:

```
drawNode(fr)
```

I have the result as below:
[image]

As you can see, right child was displayed appropriatly(of coure, not perfect location). 
But left child did not split properly. Obviously, I think the problem is in "building_tree_node" function. 
However, I had no idea because I was not familar with recursive coding. I want to know that the first left child of the tree is splited properly. My gratitude goes to any comment and idea. Additionally, I want to know about an algorithm for displaying binary tree naturally. Thank you for watching this.

Comment: in function `building_tree_node` you use `TREE` without any previouse definition or even in global scope. do your mean `Tree` instead?

Comment: Thank you for watching this. I was so stupid. I added everything needed. And I modified the second line in drawing tree. 'a' replaced by 'tree'